# How can i read in attributes from an XML document in C#?

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

For a college project i was recently assigned i need to create an XML document that will represent a chessboard. So i created elements for each space on the chessboard and then i want to assign an attribute to each space element that contains the name of the piece that is there. For example:

```
<pos piece="R"/>
```

would be a Rook.

When it comes to the C# program, how can i read in the attribute value
i am using a loop like so:

```
while(_reader.Read())
{
   if (_reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
   {
      if(_reader.HasAttributes)
      {
           //This is where i want to assign the attribute to a char
           char piece;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`XmlReader.GetAttribute()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxy2cd1w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to get XML attribute value :

```
string piece = _reader.GetAttribute("piece");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a dataset according to your xml scheme? Then you get all stuff as gift automatically. I would prefer this. Helps much and is reusable later on for any other stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Yo, here's the Microsoft tutorial hope it helps. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720458%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I made one of these a while, back when i begun programming. This may not be the most efficient way but it will work.

```
XmlReader ReadXML = XmlReader.Create("XML FILE"); //Creates XMLReader instance

   while (ReadXML.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement) //Sets the node types to closes. 
    {
       ReadXML.Read(); //Reads the XML Doc
            if (ReadXML.Name == "Child") //Focuses node 
            {
               while (ReadXML.NodeType != XmlNodeType.EndElement)//If the node is not empty
                 {
                    ReadXML.Read();
                    if (ReadXML.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Text) //Gets the text in the node
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("In 'Child' node = {0}", ReadXML.Value);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                }
          }
      }
```